# How to use GremlinPipeLine sideEffect in java

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

I would like to know how to implement the following gremlin query `g.V.has("mgrNo",T.neq,"0").sideEffect{g.V.has("empNo",it.mgrNo).next().addEdge("manages",it)}` in java using GremlinPipeLine .

I getting confused while implementing from the .next() onwards.

```
GremlinPipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("mgrNo",T.neq,0).sideEffect(new PipeFunction<Vertex, Object>(){
    @Override
    public Object compute(Vertex vertex) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        GremlinPipeline pipeline = (GremlinPipeline) new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("empNo", vertex.getProperty("mgrNo")).next();
        //code here 
        return pipeline;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, actually you already have too much code. This should work for you:

```
new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("mgrNo",T.neq,0).sideEffect(new PipeFunction<Vertex, Object>(){
    @Override
    public Object compute(Vertex vertex) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Vertex mgr = (Vertex) new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("empNo", vertex.getProperty("mgrNo")).next();
        return mgr.addEdge("manages", vertex);
    }
}).iterate();
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for helpiing with the solution

Comment: Small correction. It should be `.iterate()` instead of `,iterate()`